# Is 53°C too hot for an Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU @ 3.00GHz?

Tags: cpu, temperature

I'm using Piriform Speccy and it's saying that my Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 @ 3.00GHz CPU is running at 53 degrees Celsius... and that is at 50% load.  Is it just me, or does that seem to be a bit high?

Is this a sign I need to reapply thermal paste (it's been 2 years since I've built it, and I have never reapplied thermal paste), or check airflow in the case?

I'm wondering if my case in general is a bit too hit, as I lag when gaming, and my mouse cuts in and out (it will stop working for 2-3 seconds here and there).

Comment: What kind of chassis is it in and what else is in it?  What heatsink is on it?  It's hard to even conjecture without more details.  (IMO that temperature shouldn't be hot enough to cause problems, though.)

Comment: Not that 50% load usually means that a single core is churning away at 100%.

Comment: @Shinrai It's the factory heatsink, case is a sigma phantom wb..just a typical midtower.  My GPU is running at ~60 degrees Celsius.

Comment: @sblair Speccy says both cores are at the same temp.

Comment: "reapply thermal paste" - maybe you have too much of it? 53 c sounds hot, but within tolerance. What's it peak at under full load?

Comment: I have that exact chip. :) It's currently hovering at 49-50 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, 53°C is not too hot.

[pantherproducts](http://www.pantherproducts.co.uk/Articles/CPU/CPU%20Temperatures.shtml)

Intel Core 2 Duo (Wolfdale) 72.4°C

---

[Intel](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/core2duo/316676.pdf)

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E8400 Tc Max = 5° C to 72.4° C

---

[CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Duo%20E8400%20EU80570PJ0806M%20-%20AT80570PJ0806M%20(BX80570E8400).html)

Minimum/Maximum operating temperature (°C)  ?   5 - 72.4